# org.json.JSONException cannot be converted to JSONArray in android

Tags: android, arrays, json, webserver

When I try to connect with webserver with IP address, I got this JSON error.

```
org.json.JSONException: Value {"dsdata":{"ttlogin":[{"BundyId":"9090","Name":"IT DEVELOPMENT"}]}} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:112)
```

My java code

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        
        String login_url ="http://200.200.200.20/bin/dev/dispatch/truckunloading.p";

        try {

            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

            OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));

            String data = URLEncoder.encode("ctype", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("login", "UTF-8") + "&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("clogin", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("9090", "UTF-8");

            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            OS.close();

            Log.e("ERROR OBJECT", "Conneting");

            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));

            String response = "";
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                response += line;
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            try {
                JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.e("ERROR OBJECT", jsonobject.toString());
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return response;
            }

            return "good";
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "fail";

        } catch (IOException ee) {
            ee.printStackTrace();
            return "fail";
        }
    }
```

I searched it about everywhere but I can't resolve it.

It gives me the desirable response in the browser but I don't know what's the matter with android !

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JSONArray string is enclosed in `[]`, while a JSONObject string is enclosed in `{}`. The string you are trying to parse is not a JSONArray - it is a JSONObject, so instead of

```java
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);
```

you need to use

```java
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
```

That's why the error message says `type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray`.

Once you have the object, you can get objects or arrays that are nested within in. In this case, your JSON string looks like this:

```
{"dsdata":{"ttlogin":[{"BundyId":"9090","Name":"IT DEVELOPMENT"}]}}
```

so if you wanted to get the "ttlogin" array you could use

```java
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray arr = jsonObj.getJSONObject("dsdata").getJSONArray("ttlogin");
```